# Recognizing end of pasted contents even without a terminating newline in bash

Tags: bash, end-of-line

I am trying to dig list of domains so that I can look up only txt records.

Here's my script.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Please Enter the Domains (Multiple Domains will work):"
while read domains || [[ -n "$domains" ]]; do      
echo
    dig TXT $domains | grep TXT
done
```

It works, but it will always ignore the last text from pasted input. 
I have to manually press <kbd>return</kbd> key to get it work.

Here's my testing results

```
$sh test.sh 
Please Enter the Domains (Multiple Domains will work):
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.2
1.1.1.3
1.1.1.4 <---- these are copy and paste from clipboard

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> TXT 1.1.1.1
;1.1.1.1.           IN  TXT

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> TXT 1.1.1.2
;1.1.1.2.           IN  TXT

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> TXT 1.1.1.3
;1.1.1.3.           IN  TXT
```

(I have to press <kbd>return</kbd> at this point, to get last `dig` result)

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> TXT 1.1.1.4
;1.1.1.4.           IN  TXT
```

I've tried hours and hours searching through Google to fix it, but couldn't find the resolution. 
Any insights will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What's `$line`? Also, without pressing return, how should `read` recognize you aren't going to enter any more characters?

Comment: oops, let me revise the code.

Comment: Can't you copy with a newline after the last record? You won't get `read` to process the last line if its not a complete line.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.. sigh* I could just simply save the list of domains as a text file and run "dig TXT -f domain_lists.txt | grep TXT" like this, but my boss doesn't like it this way. lol.

Comment: You could write your own `read` program which would read from stdin, detect the paste and append a `\n` after the last line of the pasted input if it wasn't an empty line.

Comment: instead of `dig TXT $domain| grep TXT` you could use: `dig +noall +answer TXT $domains`

Comment: if your ip addresses are same lenght, you can use this; while read -n 7 domains ... in your code

Comment: @choroba by using *timeout*, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40508571/1765658) ;-)